# Ubuntu - Mic. Mute notification pop up random

Tags: ubuntu, microphone, notifications, popups, headset

laptop dell with ubuntu 18.04 upgraded to 20.04 but the issue is still appearing.
I changed a few headsets but this mute pop up notification is not disappearing, and continue showing randomly on my screen.

Comment: What's the laptop model? Is the notification visible all the time, or just sometimes? Is there any regularity to it appearing? Does the mic get muted only, or unmuted too?

Comment: Dell Latitude 5401 + Docking WD19 the problem is showing both ways with or without dock. The only mute is popping up. There is no regularity, it can happen 10 times in 5 minutes and later in 2 hours....

Comment: also even if the mic is unplugged

Comment: Does the mic LED on the keyboard (F4) light up or blink then it happens?

Comment: Same with my BT headset and Ubuntu 18.04.5 on Dell Precision 3530